# How to get bundled items in cart

Tags: magento, cart

I'm trying to make a custom cart page and need some help pulling the individual sku's that make up a bundled product.

In other words how do I pull out of the 'Quote' object the individual sku's for bundled product.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Pesach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$quote->getProduct()->getData('sku');
```